# When casting Faerie Fire from Ring of Shooting Stars, do you need to maintain concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spellcasting, concentration

Ring of Shooting Stars says

> Faerie Fire: You can expend 1 charge as an action to cast Faerie Fire ***from the ring***.

Since it says you cast the spell ***from the ring***, I wonder if you need to maintain concentration on the resulting spell.
Moreover, is that something particular to Ring of Shooting Stars, or is that how it usually goes with casting spells via items?